# Convert html tag argument with R

Tags: r, rvest, stringr

**Problem:** Using R, I aim to convert an `a href` argument for `tags` from space delimited to comma delimited and then write this back to a file.

**Background:** [Diigo](https://www.diigo.com/index) exports bookmarks as html and tags for each link are space delimited lists. When this file is imported into Firefox, the tags are not properly parsed; they become long multi-word tags. Thus, I want the `tag` argument to be a comma delimited list rather than a space delimited list.

**Sample Data**

```html
<!DOCTYPE NETSCAPE-Bookmark-file-1>
             <!-- This is an automatically generated file.
             It will be read and overwritten.
             DO NOT EDIT! -->
             <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
             <TITLE>Bookmarks</TITLE>
             <H1 LAST_MODIFIED="">Bookmarks</H1>
             <DL><p>
             <DT><H3 ID="">Diigo - Nathan Craig's Bookmarks</H3>
             <DL><p>
<DT><A HREF="https://github.com/ahb108/rcarbon/" LAST_MODIFIED="" TAGS="R-Language R-Library radiocarbon" ID="">ahb108/rcarbon: Methods for calibrating and analysing radiocarbon dates</A>
                <DD>
<DT><A HREF="https://docs.ropensci.org/c14bazAAR/index.html" LAST_MODIFIED="" TAGS="R-Language R-Library radiocarbon" ID="">Download and Prepare C14 Dates from Different Source Databases • c14bazAAR</A>
                <DD>
</DL><p>
             </DL><p>
```

**Attempted but Incomplete Solution**

```r
library(rvest)
library(stringr)
library(htmltools)
```

```r
document <- read_html(here::here("data/links.htm"))

tags <- document |> html_elements("a") |> html_attr("tags")
tags
```

`[1] "R-Language R-Library radiocarbon" "R-Language R-Library radiocarbon"`

```r
str_replace_all(tags, " ", ",")
```

`[1] "R-Language,R-Library,radiocarbon" "R-Language,R-Library,radiocarbon"`

This changes the tag vectors from space delimited to comma delimited. *How do I get this transformed information back into the original html?*

Answer (score 0):

so first of all, it seems to me, that your xml file is not valid. There is a few tags flying around that do not close, there is no root node, etc. Hence, I have modified the xml file, so that it is readable with xml2. I am not sure whether you edited it, or whether it just comes in this format. If the latter is the case, I am afraid my solution will not help you.

```xml
<!DOCTYPE NETSCAPE-Bookmark-file-1>
<!-- This is an automatically generated file.
             It will be read and overwritten.
             DO NOT EDIT! -->

<root>
        <TITLE>Bookmarks</TITLE>
        <H1 LAST_MODIFIED="">Bookmarks</H1>
        <DL>
                <DT><A HREF="https://github.com/ahb108/rcarbon/" LAST_MODIFIED=""
                                TAGS="R-Language R-Library radiocarbon" ID="">ahb108/rcarbon: Methods for calibrating
                                and
                                analysing radiocarbon dates</A>
                </DT>
                <DT><A HREF="https://docs.ropensci.org/c14bazAAR/index.html" LAST_MODIFIED=""
                                TAGS="R-Language R-Library radiocarbon" ID="">Download and Prepare C14 Dates from
                                Different
                                Source Databases • c14bazAAR</A>
                </DT>
        </DL>
</root>
```

```
library(rvest)
library(stringr)
library(xml2)
library(purrr)

## your code
document <- read_html(here::here("path/test.htm"))

tags <- document %>% html_elements("a") %>% html_attr("tags")
new_tags <- str_replace_all(tags, " ", ",")

## make a named list with new tags
## as required by xml_set_attrs
values <- map2(new_tags,'TAGS',function(.x,.y){
  x <- .x
  names(x) <- .y
  return(x)
})

## read doc as xml
document <- read_xml("path/test.htm")

## set attributes
xml_set_attrs(xml_find_all(document,xpath = 'A'), value = values)

## confirm it is working
nodes <- xml_find_all(document,xpath = 'DL//A')
xml_attrs(nodes)

## write
write_xml(document, "path/new.html")
```